# Chained animations messing up on orientation change

Tags: swift, animation, layout, swiftui

When I change the orientation the sparkle SF symbol starts moving up and down. The up and down animation is only supposed to be implemented once (on appearance). I have tried using verticalSizeClass however, that does not help.

Way it works: on appearance, the text and the SF symbol moves up and then the Sparkle SF symbol scales up and down.

This is how it looks and behaves on orientation change:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offsetY: CGFloat = 150
    @State private var opacityAmount: Double = 0
    @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "sparkle").foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .offset(y: offsetY)
                    .opacity(opacityAmount)
                    .animation(
                        Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.1)
                    )
                    .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
                Text("All new design").font(.largeTitle)
                    .offset(y: offsetY)
                    .opacity(opacityAmount)
                    .animation(
                        Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.1)
                    )
            }
            .onAppear {
                offsetY = 0
                opacityAmount = 0.8
                animationAmount = 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not adapt animation-value join from my previous answer, and observe result of that.

It is because `.animation` modifier introduces *implicit* animation, which is applied to *all* animatable view modifiers above it, that might ended up with undesired accumulated multiple animations (however sometimes it is what's needed, of course).

Here is fixed part. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "sparkle").foregroundColor(.yellow)
        .offset(y: offsetY)
        .opacity(opacityAmount)
        .animation(
            Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.1)
        , value: opacityAmount)                     // << here !!
        .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
            value: animationAmount)                // << here !!
    Text("All new design").font(.largeTitle)
        .offset(y: offsetY)
        .opacity(opacityAmount)
        .animation(
            Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.1)
        , value: opacityAmount)                           // << here !!
}
```

*Note: you can play with which animation to give explicit value or not.*

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense! I didn't know that I could use 'value: opacityAmount' and so on.